# iTerm2 disable autohide on focus out

Tags: iterm2

I wish to disable iTerm dropdown terminal autohide on focus out. I googled and tried to find the appropriate setting in the iTerm2 preferences to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open a window using a hotkey
pref->profiles->  -> Keys -> Genenal -> Configure hotkey window

the window will hide when focus out.

you may need check the [Pin hotkey window(stays open on loss of keyboard loss)] option.

Pin hotkey window

[image: 1]